# Reloading resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a list of questions in my routing's resolve. Then, I have an item view of the questions that get the question using `forEach` lwith the list from parent scope to find the item specified from `$stateParams`.

In the view, the user could answer the question. They also can view their past submissions. I need to update the list of questions to have a check mark when they have answered correctly so I think I should reload the topmost scope but there seems to be no way to reload it from `ui-router`.

Note that the only way I could know whether the user answered correctly is from submission list refresh or to refresh the problems list. Posting an answer is done by normal (non-AJAX) POST and the answer is checked asynchronously by a task queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to move the entire thing out into a service. Have that service manage the entire list of questions, and you can query it from your resolve or modify it from your parent scope, or whatever else you need to do.